# how to remove existing style dimensions in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, resize, paperclip

I know you can add new styles to paper clip and then use process! method to force paperclip to fill in the missing styles.  But what if you want to ditch the old styles that you are not using any more.

For example I have styles iphone and ipad, and I changed my mind and would instead like :large and :medium with slightly different dimensions instead of :iphone and :ipad.

In particular I'm hosting my images on s3 since my app is on heroku.  I would like to remove all the folders on s3 pertaining to :iphone and :ipad styles.  Is there a rake task for removing select styles?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to use the s3 GUI tool?

Comment: There is no way to do this with paperclip, only regenerate/refresh new or existing styles. You should be able to script something using aws-s3 gem http://amazon.rubyforge.org

Comment: I'd be there all day with the gui tool.  There are 300 posts with images.  I was hoping for a method like post.image(:ipad).delete which would in turn delete the file off of s3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to removing invalid files, try:

```
rake paperclip:clean  # Cleans out invalid attachments.
```

You can view all paperclip tasks in your console by typing:

```
rake -T paperclip
```

Comment: The `clean` task also requires a class to be specified.

Answer (score 2):

run in your terminal

```
rake -T paperclip
```

you can see like this

```
...
rake paperclip:clean                    # Cleans out invalid attachments.
rake paperclip:refresh                  # Refreshes both metadata and thumbnails.
rake paperclip:refresh:metadata         # Regenerates content_type/size metadata for a given CLASS (and optional ATTACHMENT).
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles   # Regenerates missing thumbnail styles for all classes using Paperclip.
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails       # Regenerates thumbnails for a given CLASS (and optional ATTACHMENT and STYLES splitted by comma).
...
```

for refreshing your thumbnail try this

```
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails class= Xyz # xyz replace with your class name
```

for removing

```
rake paperclip:clean                    # Cleans out invalid attachments.
```

Comment: The `clean` task also requires a class to be specified.

Comment: is it possible to perform this function for single upload and directly from application? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Attachment#clear` method.

If you wanted to delete the `thumb` and `display` styles, you could run something like:

```rb
YourModel.find_each do |ym|
  ym.attachment.clear(:display, :thumb)
  ym.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a script to accomplish this, but paperclip does have a `s3_object` convenience method that makes this easy:

```
obj = User.first.avatar.s3_object(:unwanted_style)
obj.delete if obj.exists?
```

You could place something like this within a loop for any objects you want to operate on.

Sources:

- [`Paperclip::Storage::S3` documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3#s3_object-instance_method)
- [aws-sdk Object documentaion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html)