# Remove paperclip style without reprocess image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

i need to remove paperclip style from filesystem without reprocess image, is this possible?
Should i remove them manually?

thank you all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove existing style dimensions in paperclip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702078/how-to-remove-existing-style-dimensions-in-paperclip)

Answer (score 0):

i think you only need to remove this style.

Then you won't access images with this type.

And if you want to save hard disk space, you can manually remove the folder of this style.

This is all I can tell you without more details of your project.

If you can post some details, I am glade to discuss with you further.

Comment: hi Chuanpin, thanks for the reply. Yes i would like to save disk space and i'm wondering if there is some paperclip method to delete styles directly to the hard drive. Without removing manually cause they are so many. Also i cannot reprocess them because lots of them are generated with multiple layers of png and it would take long time to reprocess them all.